# How to use method all for elements with two classes

Tags: capybara

This code don't work

```
descriptions = []
page.all('div', class: 'news-tidings__speech news-helpers_hide_mobile-small').each do |el|
  descriptions.push(el.text[1..200])
end
```

one part of HTML:

```html
<div class="news-tidings__speech news-helpers_hide_mobile-small">text </div>
```

Comment: okey... I should use only first class name)))

Comment: page.all('div', class: 'news-tidings__speech').each do |el|
  descriptions.push(el.text[1..200])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do what you want.

1. Just use a standard CSS selector with multiple classes

   ```
   page.all('div.news-tidings__speech.news-helpers_hide_mobile-small')
   ```
2. If you want to use the `:class` option it will take an array of the desired classes (element must have all the classes)

   ```
   page.all('div', class: ['div.news-tidings__speech','news-helpers_hide_mobile-small'])
   ```
3. It you want to make sure those are the only classes, and in a specific order, on the element then you can use a CSS attribute selector

   ```
   page.all("div[class='news-tidings__speech news-helpers_hide_mobile-small']")
   ```